# NGX-Graph Nodes turns black when using third property

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, material-ui, ngx-graph

I'm trying to make a crone tree using **ngx-graph**, and link each node to a pop-up so i went for the "**@material-extended/mde**", the issue i have is that i'm trying to define the pop-up content by node, so i tried using the property "**data**". But, whenever i add any new property to the nodes (other than **id and label**), the parse fails and all nodes turn black.

Is there any way i can make the pop-up content work, i'm planning to have **forms** and **data grids** into the pop-up depending on the node?

[Here is a link to the stackblitz i'm working on](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-graph-demo-jkpx9a)

It always fails on the node with the additional field, so i thought it should be a parse issue, or node **structure is predefined** and cannot have the graph with more than the 2 fields (id and label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `node.data = 'testdata'` you overwrite the original `node.data` property which is used in example for `node.data.color`.

To solve your issue you can define the data object and create your own property inside

E.g.

Component:

```
{
    id: 'First',
    label: '12/10/2012 - 12/10/2013',
    data: { tooltip:'First testdata' }
  }
```

Html:

```
 <mat-card-content>
     Here goes data form/data grid {{node.data?.tooltip}}
 </mat-card-content>
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-graph-demo-tfrknm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

---

However `node.data` is already used by ngx-graph mabye you want to define your own property to avoid any side effects.

E.g.

Component:

```
{
    id: 'First',
    label: '12/10/2012 - 12/10/2013',
    tooltip:'First testdata'
  }
```

Html:

```
 <mat-card-content>
     Here goes data form/data grid {{node.tooltip}}
 </mat-card-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works, i created the property inside the object data. Unfortunately i wasn't able to define a new Node property as the component is locked and had to use one of the already defined properties for it. Thanks again.